.feature file is not being recognized when trying to execute .feature file with webdriverIO
enter image description here
enter image description here
Trying to execute
npx wdio --spec .\step_definitions\Loginfeature.feature
I am able to see the app open but as soon as it does, the app crashes
[0-0] 2024-07-21T15:51:01.750Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
[0-0] 2024-07-21T15:51:01.982Z WARN @wdio/mocha-framework: Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on browser object that is not fully initialized.
[0-0] browser object has only capabilities and some flags like isMobile.
[0-0] Helper files that use other browser commands have to be moved to before hook.
[0-0] Spec file(s): file:///C:/Users/anup1/mobile-app-automation/step_definitions/Loginfeature.feature
[0-0] Error: Error: ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION .feature C:\Users\anup1\mobile-app-automation\step_definitions\Loginfeature.feature
